# How to create non-minified and minified builds with babel

Tags: node.js, babeljs, minify, babel-preset-env, babel-preset-minify

I installed below babel modules

```
npm install babel-cli babel-preset-env babel-preset-minify --save-dev
```

and `package.json` has

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "babel src -d dist --copy-files"
}
```

When I run the build with below `.babelrc` configurations

```
{
  "presets": [
    "env"
  ],
  "comments": false
}
```

It generates the non minified build into `dist` directory.

But I want to also have the minified builds of as well along with non-minified ones. I tried adding both presets in `.babelrc` as below

```
{
  "presets": [
    "minify", "env"
  ],
  "comments": false
}
```

but it's not generating both the minified and non-minified builds. In this case only minified version is generated.

Is there any way to ask babel to create both minified & non-minified builds like `index.js` & `index.min.js` in the `dist` directory.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way of doing it:

`package.json` scripts:

```
  "scripts": {
    "build:dev": "babel src -d dist --copy-files",
    "build:min": "BABEL_ENV=minify babel src -d dist --out-file-extension .min.js",
    "build": "npm run build:dev && npm run build:min"
  }
```

`.babelrc` config:

```
{  
  presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
  comments: false,
  env: {
    minify: {
      presets: ['@babel/preset-env', ['babel-preset-minify']],
    },
  }
}
```

Then run `npm run build`